# Flutter animated_text_kit ColorizeAnimatedText()

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to use `ColorizeAnimatedText()` in my Flutter app, the result is like this:[image]

This is my code:

```dart
Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  child: AnimatedTextKit(
                    animatedTexts: [
                      ColorizeAnimatedText(
                        "Test Text",
                        colors: colorizeColors,
                        textStyle: GoogleFonts.inconsolata(fontSize: 27),
                      ),
                    ],
                    pause: Duration(milliseconds: 0),
                    isRepeatingAnimation: true,
                    repeatForever: true,
                  )
                ),
```

I don't get any errors. The gif was recorded in Flutter Web but when I try it on Android it gives the same result too.

`flutter doctor -v`:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1165], locale tr-TR)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (7 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\emirs\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.7.3)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.7.30503.244
    X The current Visual Studio installation is incomplete. Please reinstall Visual Studio.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[√] VS Code (version 1.56.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\emirs\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.22.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1165]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 85.0.4183.102
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 92.0.902.73

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

What I'm trying to achieve is something similar to [this](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit#colorize) but with only 1 text.

Comment: The code is correctly what was your problem

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Thats my problem. The code is correct but it doesn't work.